# Google Analytics User Activity showing wrong Event Parameters

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

After creating a report using the Explore (Analysis) tool on Google Analytics, we've created a report for all the users that have triggered a specific event. but once we click on that user to view his User's Activities, we found the following issues:

- Numeric Event Parameters are being shown with 6 extra zeros. (i.e. actual value=5, shown value=5000000).
- It is not showing all the Event Parameters that we are sending with the event

2 notes that should be mentioned:

- at the same time, we've checked BigQuery for those records and saw that the number event parameters values are correct (without zeros) and all event parameters are being stored correctly.
- the numeric Event parameter has been registered as Standard